# looping in selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to make a loop in python with selenium, where it will keep reopening a page and clicking a button then closing and opening the page again. but I cant seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

here is the code, with the website removed

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

i = 1
while i < 100:
    driver.get("random_page")
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//button[data-option=1214]"))
    button.click()
    i += 1
```

Comment: _but I cant seem to get it to work_ It would help if you said what the **actual problem** was...

Comment: my poblem is that i cant get the loop to work. I want the webpage to be opened and a button to be clicked. apon clicking the button selenium closes the browser, but I want it to reopen the browser and click the button again.

Comment: I don't see anything in the loop that would close the browser.  Why is it closing?

Comment: selenium does it automatically after a button is clicked

Comment: So that button element has javascript attached to it which makes the browser close?  That's very strange.

Comment: ikr? i thought it was weird to. i just want the loop to work hahaha i know its probably simple but i cant seem to think of it

Comment: Is the button clicked the first time the page opens? What happens if you add a delay and/or explicitly close the driver?

Comment: where is the rest of the code ?   the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)